# Drupal 8, modular content, and syndication

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8, syndication

I am trying to sketch out a Drupal 8 based solution by which content is authored in a modular way, with an arbitrary number of different modular blocks of content, (similar to Sir Trevor https://madebymany.github.io/sir-trevor-js/) that would also allow nodes to be pushed (or pulled) to other separate Drupal 8 installs (similar to content push https://www.drupal.org/project/content_push). So far I can't seem to find any obvious solutions, most seem to require knowledge of the content configuration beforehand. Is there an obvious solution I'm overlooking or just ignorant of?

Comment: Sounds like a combination of the Paragraphs Module: https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs and the deploy module: https://www.drupal.org/project/deploy

Comment: This seems pretty close, I'm not sure how easily it will allow content to move between Drupal installations. It doesn't quite cover every use case that I might need, so I wish how easy to extend was a little more obvious but it's definitely a strong contender for what I need. Thanks!

Comment: The purpose of deploy is to move content between installations and to eventually cover all reasonable use cases, but nothing about that process is easy so easy extension to complex workflows are hard to envision. I suggest you try those modules and see how far they get you, and attempt your extensions so you can asked detailed questions. You may get better assistance to non-programming Drupal questions on http://drupal.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is currently not possible for Drupal 8, using community maintained modules. The Feeds Extensible Parsers module is not ready, which means the services+feeds method for disseminating content is not feasible, and the Deploy module is not ready. (Though methods may become available in the future for this particular workflow.)